# how to do horizontal scroll in ionic 3

Tags: css, angular, scroll, ionic2, ionic3

look at my [image]

I have 10 names in the ion-scroll but it is coming to the next line like a paragraph.

here is my .html code.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100vw; height:50px" >
        <ion-row class="headerChip">
          <div *ngFor="let tabName of product_type; let idx = index" [ngClass]="showSelectedTabArray[idx].showSelectedTab ? 'headerChipGray' : 'headerChipGreen'">
          <ion-chip  (click)="changeData(tabName)">
          <ion-label  >{{tabName.languagename}}</ion-label>
          <div></div>
          </ion-chip>
          </div>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-scroll>
```

here is my css

```
.headerChipGray{
    ion-chip.chip.chip-md{
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        background: white;
    }
    ion-chip.chip.chip-ios{
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        background: white;
    }
}

.headerChipGreen{

    ion-chip.chip.chip-md{
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: white;
        color: #A80C50;
        border: 1px solid #A80C50;
    }

    ion-chip.chip.chip-ios{
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: white;
        color: #A80C50;
        border: 1px solid #A80C50;
    }
}
```

> this same piece of code used to work in ionic 2 after updating to ionic 3 i am facing this issue what i am missing ionic doc for ion-scroll

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like [`ion-row`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Row/) within your scroll is wrapping the items.

Try using `nowrap` attribute.

> Adds flex-wrap: nowrap. Forces the columns to a single row.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100vw; height:50px" >
  <ion-row nowrap class="headerChip">
    <div *ngFor="let tabName of product_type; let idx = index" [ngClass]="showSelectedTabArray[idx].showSelectedTab ? 'headerChipGray' : 'headerChipGreen'">
    <ion-chip  (click)="changeData(tabName)">
    <ion-label  >{{tabName.languagename}}</ion-label>
    <div></div>
    </ion-chip>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Your answer save me

Answer (score 6):

This simple CSS styling will get your job done more easier. Wrap your content inside a `div` and add the below styling to that `div`. This should work irrespective of any Ionic version. However, I'm using **Ionic 5**.

**CSS / SCSS**

```js
.horizontal-scroll {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll">
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>Java</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>Node.js</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>Fusion.js</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>React</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>Redux</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>Angular</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
  <ion-chip>
    <ion-label>JavaScript</ion-label>
  </ion-chip>
</div>
```

You can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic4-horizontal-scroll?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) for working example that I've created.

Comment: plus 1 for, correct answer is this bcz ion-scroll is deprecated

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara I was beating myself here whole day wondering why `ion-scroll` is not working

Comment: @Morgs because it is deprecated and we can not able to use. So we have accept no other clues. Above code worked for me.

Comment: Man, I really appreciated! Awesome workaround